# Downloading Jupyter notebook from external URL using CLI

Tags: curl, jupyter-notebook, wget, jupyter

I need to download .ipynb-file in a terminal and than run it (using `nbconvert` or something like that).

1. I tried use `wget` and `curl` for this, but I got web page (with tags and Javascript code) instead of runnable Notebook.
2. Then I used [Jupyter REST API](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-Notebook-Server-API). To get a notebook's content I used `/api/contents/<path>/<file>` I.e. I simply changed `notebooks` to `api/contents` in URL. I got a content of the notebook with some additional text (I'll have to filter it later), and... in a form of one line. So, I have a lot of work to convert this one line into a working notebook.

Is it possible to download Jupyter notebook via terminal and to get working .ipynb-file (the same as file can be downloaded by `download as .ipynb` in Jupyter Web UI).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Authorization header and Content-Type application/json and then the notebook will be in the "content" part of the dictionary that is returned. You can use jq to get the content part of the dictionary. If on Mac OS X just `brew install jq`

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token {YOUR_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XGET https://{YOUR_JUPYTER_DOMAIN}/user/{USERNAME}/api/contents/{PATH_TO_IPYNB} | jq ".content"
```

Also you can add output redirection after the jq part > my_downloaded.ipynb

And then just open it with jupyter notebook

For /user make sure your personal server is started, for this you have to login to your user account or go into your Control panel, if it is not on or has been culled.
For /services the server is usually being proxied so it should always be on.

The Url to use for /services

```
https://{YOUR_JUPYTER_DOMAIN}/services/{SERVICENAME}/api/contents/{PATH_TO_IPYNB}
```

Comment: and how to achieve the authorization token? @sigurdb

Comment: @AviralSrivastava https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/rest.html#create-an-api-token

Answer (score 2):

I've also found simple solution. But it is applicable only if the notebook **isn't secured by a token**. The notebooks can be downloaded by `wget`.

Assume that our notebook is located by the following URL:

```
http://<DOMAIN>:<PORT>/notebooks/my_notebook.ipynb
```

We can simply replace "notebooks" to "files" and download the source ipynb-file by the following command:

```
wget http://<DOMAIN>:<PORT>/files/my_notebook.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on jupyter, but if you can do `download as .ipynb` and get the file using the browser, then just repeat that step with Chrome developer tools open, and look for the URL that the browser hit in the network tab.  You can copy as curl command in developer tools and paste that in a terminal to get the same effect.  (sorry I don't have a running notebook to ensure that my advice works, hope it helps)